# How can I read only a single line from text file which contains multiple lines?

Tags: c++

Suppose there are 10 lines in a text file , Using C++ File handling, I want that only that line prints on screen which started from a specific word. Please Help me so that I complete my Project.

Comment: come on, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If I could make some suggestions to improve your question in order to more likely get an answer: 1. Show an attempt at trying to do this yourself (post some code, show some research effort) 2. Google this before you ask it (you could find an answer)  3. Read the "how to ask a question" that comes up when asking a question. You can't expect someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header to read a line into a `std::string`.

Put that in a loop to read lines until you encounter one that starts with the "specific word", or reading failed.

If line found, display that line.

---

Sub-task: find out how to check whether a `std::string` starts with a specific word.